# ASP.NET VB.NET GridView adding anchor tag to a cell

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have an GridView control with some data in the first cell throughout the column. Ineed to make that cell data into a hyperlink (anchor tag) like the following.

```
<a href=""myPage.aspx?r=" & strParam & """>" & strData & "</a>"
```

Can anyone advise on the most effective way to do this? I am using a datatable and then assigning the datatable to the gridview. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I need to use the  Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs). So I could add a hyperlink whatabout getting the parameters into the RowDataBound event is where my skills are falling down.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume when you are binding the data to gridview, strParam and strData are in datasource
then do like below

```
<a href ="myPage.aspx?r=<%# Eval("strParam")%>">  <asp:Label ID="lblView" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("strData ")%>'></asp:Label></a>
```